# Search Toolbar Register issues?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, search-window

When i have to use search tool, it will come warning dialogue box. How can I solve this issue.
I have attached an example image to show the warning dialogue box.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am missing something, either:

- On the dropdown that says Enterprise currently, select Local to perform local searches, or
- Register an enterprise search service (requires ArcGIS Server).

This is also explained in the help: [Using search in ArcGIS](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00660000007q000000)